# Why doesn't nethogs show correct total

Tags: nethogs

This happens from time to time and I can't find out what's utilizing part of by bandwidth.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem/question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Nethogs monitors udp traffic.(although it appears that this is a requested [enhancement](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/issues/62)